# php return last edit on SQL with SSE

Tags: php, variables, server-sent-events

I have a php script which enters/returns json formatted data to/from a database.
i want to create a SSE script which returns the last time an update to the database was made.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
echo "last update:$last";
?>
```

How do i this safely and efficiently that?

the options i see:

- sql request - not very efficient.
- APC store - not supported on the
  server
- store in file - not supported/safe
- session - only for one user.

im looking for a simple variable being passed between scripts.

Comment: If you just want to pass values between pages, then you can use `$_SESSION` global array variable. But i think, the best if you store it on serverside, i.e. in sql.